# How do I find the definition point of an operand in LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, llvm

Since LLVM uses Static Single Assignment Form, every operand is assigned a value exactly once. For some given instruction, I retrieve its operands, and I then want to find the instruction where the the operand was assigned its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are basically the same. Say, you have

```
i32 %1 = inst1
inst2 i32 %1
```

When you do `inst2->getOperand(0)`, you get a `Value*` pointing to `%1`. If you need to follow the chain of instructions, you'd need to call `getOperand` over and over.